# How do I disable React PropType validation?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, storybook, react-proptypes

How do I disable React PropType validation? I use TypeScript and have not defined PropTypes for any of my components. However, I use Create React App (CRA) and Storybook for development, and they seem to be performing PropType validation based on rules they pick up from 3rd party libraries. Are the validators run implicitly by React as part of normal execution, or are they executed explicitly by CRA and Storybook? How do I turn off the validation feature?